# RStudio imputeLCMD and sea packages install problem

Tags: r

The computer is showing this:

```
library(imputeLCMD)
```

> Loading required package: tmvtnorm Loading required package: mvtnorm
> Loading required package: Matrix Loading required package: stats4
> Loading required package: gmm Loading required package: sandwich
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gmm’ in dyn.load(file,
> DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):  unable to load shared object
> '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/gmm/libs/gmm.so':
>
> dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/gmm/libs/gmm.so,
> 0x0006): Library not loaded: '/usr/local/gfortran/lib/libgomp.1.dylib'
> Referenced from: '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/gmm/libs/gmm.so'
> Reason: tried: '/usr/local/gfortran/lib/libgomp.1.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (arm64), need
> (x86_64h))),
> '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libgomp.1.dylib' (no
> such file), '/Users/luoyihan/lib/libgomp.1.dylib' (no such file),
> '/usr/local/lib/libgomp.1.dylib' (no such file),
> '/usr/lib/libgomp.1.dylib' (no such file), '/lib/libgomp.1.dylib' (no
> such file),
> '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libgomp.1.dylib'
> (no such file),
> '/var/folders/kp/qqn1yfxj7f37ww7b1hlfc8k80000gp/T/rstudio-fallback-library-path-a1a8GD/libgomp.1.dylib'
> (no
> Error: package ‘gmm’ could not be loaded

I have re-download my r and cleaned my r packages as well, but I still get this error.

Comment: Have you verified the file path is correct? https://community.rstudio.com/t/unable-to-load-shared-object-on-startup-in-rstudio-only/33107.

Comment: can you share what is the output when you try this: install.packages("gmm")

Comment: @cgrafe Thanks for responding, I tried this: Sys.getenv("PATH")
Sys.which("stats.dll"), and the returns this: > Sys.getenv("PATH")
[1] "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/luoyihan/Applications/quarto/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/texbin:/private/var/folders/kp/qqn1yfxj7f37ww7b1hlfc8k80000gp/T/AppTranslocation/6638CE63-A32C-401A-AA69-A27744A93579/d/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/quarto/bin:/private/var/folders/kp/qqn1yfxj7f37ww7b1hlfc8k80000gp/T/AppTranslocation/6638CE63-A32C-401A-AA69-A27744A93579/d/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS"
> Sys.which("stats.dll")
stats.dll 
       ""

Comment: @WasimAftab, Hi there, thanks for helping, the output is this: install.packages("gmm") 
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.2/gmm_1.7.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1436692 bytes (1.4 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.4 MB


The downloaded binary packages are in
 /var/folders/kp/qqn1yfxj7f37ww7b1hlfc8k80000gp/T//RtmpmJXp72/downloaded_packages. But when I run gmm, it gives me error again.